# Wave packet for particle in a potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, dispersion

In the book Quantum Mechanics by Cohen-Tannoudji, the author explains that the solutions of the Schrodinger equation of a free particle in one dimension are plane waves:

$$\psi (x, t) = A e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$$

And that every linear combination of such plane waves that satisfy

$$\omega = \frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}.$$

Will also be a solution of the S.E., thanks to the principle of superposition. Such a superposition can be written:

$\psi (x, t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int g(k) e^{i[kx-\omega (k)t]}dk$

At $t=0$, the wave packet takes the form

$\psi (x, 0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int g(k) e^{ikx}dk$

And we immediately see that $g(k)$ is simply the Fourier transform of $\psi(x,0)$:

$g(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int \psi (x, 0) e^{-ikx}dk$

Now, the following paragraph is where my confusion arises. The author states:

> "Consequently, the validity of formula (C-8) (the formula for $\psi(x,0)$ above) is not limited to the case of the free particle: whatever the potential, $\psi(x,0)$ can always be written in this form".

How can the author be sure of this? After all, he arrived to this result by treating the case of a free particle. If I had a particle in a potential, instead of a free particle, then the solutions would not be plane waves, and the whole treatment would be different

Comment: a generalized Fourier Transform can be defined for tempered distributions, see that section in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)

Comment: He never gets to use the dispersion relation $\omega(k)$ he found for the free particle, so for any potential his Ansatz is valid, for different dispersion relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the time development of a quantum state in the Schrodinger picture, the potential only effects the eigenvalues and eigenstates of the Hamiltonian, i.e. the eigenstates and energy levels found by solving the time independent Schrodinger equation. However, the general solution requires the use of boundary conditions to determine the expansion coefficients uniquely. Thus, the initial state, $\psi(x,0)$ informs one of the nature of the ensuing eigenfunction expansion that makes up the general solution of the time independent Schrodinger equation, however, the initial state itself has less restrictions on the form that it may assume, i.e. the Hamiltonian does not govern the nature of $\psi(x,0)$.

For $\psi(x,0)$, the only condition one needs to assume is that $\psi(x,0)$ is an element of Hilbert space, i.e. that it is square integrable over the region of space in which the problem is defined. Functions in Hilbert space posses the necessary "well-behaved" qualities that guarantee the existence of a Fourier transform, in this sense one can Fourier analyze any quantum state, not just the initial state. Thus, one has that for any solution of the time independent Schrodinger equation:
$$\psi(x)={1\over\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(k)e^{ikx}\; dk.$$ And, also:
$$g(k)={1\over \sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\psi(x)e^{-ikx}\; dx.$$
Even though the free particle eigenstates are not members of Hilbert space, linear combinations over the continuous eigenvalues are, thus free particle wave packets and other such reasonably "localized" free particle states (well-tempered distributions) can be Fourier analyzed. In fact, this is what is being said when one writes the solution as:
$$\psi(x,t)={1\over\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(k)e^{i(kx-\omega(k) t)}\; dk,$$
the above expression is easily recognizable as the definition of a Fourier transformation for any well-behaved function $g(k)$, with a time dependence given by $e^{\omega(k)t}$.
For a non-free state one may write:
$$\psi(x,t)={1\over\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(k)e^{i(kx-Et/\hbar)}\; dk.$$Here, rather than the energy assuming any continuous value $E=\hbar \omega(k)$, as for the free particle, the *total* energy is a constant $E$. In both cases the initial condition reduces to:
$$\psi(x,0)={1\over\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(k)e^{ikx}\; dk.$$
Now, why is it that the plane waves $e^{ikx}$ appear in all of these expressions despite the fact that the presence of a potential casues the solutions to the Schrodinger equation to take on forms other than $e^{ikx}$? To understand this one needs to see the Fourier transformation as a change of basis, i.e. a formula for writing a generic quantum state $g$ in the "momentum basis", as a state $\psi$ in the "position basis". In this case, the "plane waves" are eigenfunctions of the momentum operator $\hat p$, written in the position basis, $|k\rangle$ and $g(k)$ are the coefficients of the generalized Fourier expansion. So expanding the state $\psi(x)$ in terms of the position basis:
$$|\psi(x)\rangle=\Sigma_x \Sigma_k |x\rangle\langle x|k\rangle\langle k|g(k)\rangle.$$ Here, $\langle k|x\rangle$ are the momentum eigenfunctions written in the position basis or "plane waves", while the $\langle k|g(k)\rangle$ are the momentum space wave functions serving as Fourier coefficients.. I have written the expansion as for discreet eigenvalues, however, one only needs to convert the sums to integrals over $x,k$ respectively to generalize for the case of continuous spectra.

Fourier analysis of the initial state is often useful, for instance, one might be given only that a particle starts out in some state of momentum, e.g. say that the particle's initial momentum state is such that the state's component momenta are *normally* distributed about zero. One can find $\psi(x,0)$ from this information by inverting the momentum space initial condition: $$\psi(x,0)={1\over\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{1\over \sqrt {2\pi}}e^{-k^2/2}\; dk.$$ Note that this result, as a consequence of the Fourier inversion theorem, is true regardless of whether one is solving the free particle, infinite square well, or other Hamiltonian with potential $V(x)$.

Comment: I think your formulaes must be correct as sqrt (2\pi)

Comment: Thanks, I will fix it right away!

Comment: Thank you for the very insightful answer! But, to be sure: all of this is assuming a potential $V(x)$, right? Would the same treatment be valid for a potential that may be time-dependent? Since, in that case, I can't generally solve Schrodinger's equation via separation of variables, which is where I would normally obtain the function $\phi(t)=e^{-i\omega t}$ that gives time evolution and allows the treatment in your answer

Comment: @driver99 Technically, the stuff holds true for any $\psi(x,0)$ even if the Hamiltonian is time dependent, because any $\psi(x,0)$ (initial state) must be a square integrable element of Hilbert space. On the other hand, you are right in that $\Psi(x,t)$ would indeed be different because of the time dependent Hamiltonian. In that case the time development is handled with a *Dyson Series*.

Comment: This clears everything up. Thank you!!

Comment: @driver99 No problem glad to help!